# Formatting DateTime string inside of a linq statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime-format

I have a web api set up where I'm displaying information on my site via entity framework. I'm filtering my data so it only pulls back the specific parts I want, which includes a `DateTime` value.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Log> XmlLog()
{
   var userLog = _db.Logs.Where(x => x.EngineType == "Xml");

   return userLog .ToList();
 }
```

This displays my date as:

`2019-02-05T15:11:50.39`

What I need to do is change the `DateTime` format to be something else. Ideally: 
`Saturday 2 February 9:12:30`

On my linq call I've tried the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Log> XmlLog()
{
   var userLog = _db.Logs.Select(d => d.LogDate.ToString("f")).Where(x => x.EngineType == "Xml");

   return userLog .ToList();
 }
```

And on my model itself I have tried the following attributes:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
```

Neither of my attempts has worked. What is it I'm doing wrong in my statements?

The above is written in DotNet 4.7 and not in DotNetCore.

Comment: What does a failure look like? What do you expect? I'm pretty sure you should be getting an exception since `string` doesn't define a property `EngineType`.

Comment: For completeness, is this the full framework Entity Framework (not EF Core) ?

Comment: I've updated my question. It's written in full framework and not EF Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) has commented, your LINQ should be throwing an exception, because you first select strings, and then try to filter them as though they are objects.

But this approach is backwards anyway. This is just about getting the data, so it should just stay as it is, without any formatting. Let your view layer be responsible for formatting.

The `DisplayFormat` attribute is great, but only if you are using `Html.DisplayFor`/`Html.EditorFor` helpers. If you are doing just something like `@Model.LogDate` in your view, consider calling `ToString(format)` with the format you need.

Finally, your format does not look like example you wish it was. The correct format you are looking for is: `dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm:ss`.

All in all, leave the filter as it is, and either use `DisplayFor` with this annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

...

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LogDate)
```

Or don't bother with any annotations, and just use

```
@Model[i].LogDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm:ss")
```